# How to view or download binary files in the Fossil repo using the web ui?

Tags: fossil

It is possible to view images (at least JPEG) while browsing `Files` in `fossil ui`, but I could not find a way to view or download other binary files, such as pdf and other popular formats. Is there a magic switch somewhere? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of binary files, I think only images can be viewed via the web UI by default.
If you know how to display a certain type of file in a browser (like, say, PDFs using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)), you *could* adapt the skin to add this using Javascript.

All files in the repository can be downloaded, whether they’re binary or not: just use the ‘Download’ button at the top of the artifact page.